Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8081/api/auth/login due to access control checks
Summary
I am using NextJS as frontend service and ExpressJS as backend service. I am using getServerSideProps for SSR in some of my pages. For the cors issue on production, I am setting proxy while calling the backend service.
So, I have configured next.config.mjs file like below
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API}/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },

I am calling the backend API like this.
login: async (credentials) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${AUTH_API_URL}/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const { data } = await response.json();
        return data;
      } else {
        const { message } = await response.json();
        throw new Error(message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Throw the error for the component to handle
      throw new Error(error.message);
    }
  }

When running locally it works well on pc. But when opening the page from mobile device from 192.168.0.127 under same network, I am getting cors error.
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8081/api/auth/login due to access control checks.
P.S: I have allowed all origin in express backend.
Additional information
//next.config.mjs

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
import withBundleAnalyzer from '@next/bundle-analyzer';
withBundleAnalyzer({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === true
})

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['natsarytest.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'via.placeholder.com'],
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/upcoming',
        permanent: false
      },
    ]
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(.*)', // Matches all routes
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
            value: 'true',
          },
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            value: '*', // You can also restrict this to specific origins
          },
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
            value: 'GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT',
          },
          {
            key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            value: 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization',
          },
          {
            key: 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control',
            value: 'on'
          },
          {
            key: 'X-Frame-Options',
            value: 'SAMEORIGIN'
          }
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_EXTERNAL_API}/:path*`,
      },
    ];
  },
}

export default nextConfig;


// express
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import routes from "../api";
import config from "../config";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import i18next from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-fs-backend";
import i18nextMiddleware from "i18next-http-middleware";
import path from "path";
import { StatusCodes } from "http-status-codes";
import { isCelebrateError } from "celebrate";
import LoggerInstance from "./logger";

export default async ({ app }: { app: express.Application }): Promise<any> => {
  /**
   * Health Check endpoints
   * @TODO Explain why they are here
   */
  app.get("/status", (req, res) => {
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).end();
  });

  i18next
    .use(Backend)
    .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
      backend: {
        loadPath: path.join(
          __dirname,
          "../resources/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
        ),
      },
      fallbackLng: "en",
      preload: ["en"],
    });
  app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));

  app.set("view engine", "ejs");

  // Useful if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS ELB, Nginx, etc)
  // It shows the real origin IP in the heroku or Cloudwatch logs
  app.enable("trust proxy");

  // app.use(cors());

  app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // If needed

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

  // Some sauce that always add since 2014
  // "Lets you use HTTP verbs such as PUT or DELETE in places where the client doesn't support it."
  // Maybe not needed anymore ?
  app.use(require("method-override")());

  // Middleware that transforms the raw string of req.body into json
  app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
  app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
    })
  );
  app.use(cookieParser());

  // Load API routes
  // use this for local testing
  //  app.use(config.api.prefix, routes());

  //  Use these while deployment
  app.use(routes());

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new Error("Not Found");
    err["status"] = StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND;
    next(err);
  });


  // Error handler
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (isCelebrateError(err)) {
      let message = "";
      for (const value of err.details.values()) {
        message += value.message + "; ";
      }
      LoggerInstance.error(
        "JOI Validating API: %s, error: %s, body: %o",
        req.originalUrl,
        message,
        req.body
      );
      return res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({ message });
    }

    res.status(err.status || StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    const json: any = {
      message: err.message,
    };
    if (err.data) {
      json.data = err.data;
    }
    res.json(json);
  });
};

I tried hitting the API directly without proxy, Still I am getting the CORS error.
